# Odoo 8: Many2many domain filter

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I have several organization types with a many2many relation describing which types that may be parent to other types (e.g. department can be parent to sub-department and working group). It's NOT a strict hierarchy (working group can be parent to other working groups), hence the many2many relation.

I have two fields on my organization_type object: `allowed_parent_type_ids` and the inverse `allowed_children_type_ids`.

Now I want to restrict the organization type field on my organization object depending on it's parent, so a child of a "department" can only select the organization types allowed to be children of departments and so on.

In my form view, I tried:

```
<field
    name="organization_type_id"
    domain="[('id', 'in', parent_id.organization_type_id.allowed_children_ids)]"
    />
```

I also tried to put a related field with allowed types on my organization object, but I always ends up with an error message.
My last attempt was:

```
domain=[('id', 'in', allowed_type_ids)]
```

That gives an error message:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

The client actually fetches a JSON object like "allowed_type_ids" = `[0,1,2]` and if I replace allowed_type_ids in the domain expression with `[0,1,2]` there are no errors and I get the three organization types in my selection...

Comment: Try using domain="[('id', 'in', allowed_children_ids[0][2])]"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
<field
    name="organization_type_id"
    domain="[('id', 'in', parent_id.organization_type_id.allowed_children_ids.ids)]"
    />
```

While `allowed_children_ids` is a set of records, `allowed_children_ids.ids` is a list of ids of those records.

You can also approach this from the other side. This should work and be event faster:

```
<field
    name="organization_type_id"
    domain="[('allowed_parent_type_ids', '=', parent_id.organization_type_id)]"
    />
```

Comment: I couldn't get the first solution to work (I had tried something similar), but the second approach worked. I used 'in' as operator. It doesn't seem logic to have "ids in id", but it works...

Answer (score 5):

EDIT: This trick doesn't work anymore in 9.0 and 10.0 even at the time I posted the message if your Odoo codebase was up to date see https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/16072 for more details.

For an alternative you can give a try to web_domain_field module.
It is currently here: https://github.com/OCA/web/pull/567

---

Former answer:

To have a domain on a Many2many you will find a good answer from Olivier Dony on the Odoo FAQ: https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/aide-1/question/complex-many2many-domains-in-views-41777#answer_41784

In short, you need to adress the correct values as the Many2many value is a list of tuple like `[(6, 0, ids)]`.

Thus you need to create a domain like this to compare ids:

```
domain=[('id', 'in', allowed_type_ids[0][2])]
```

Warning, this might not work on Odoo 9.0 in the case your many2many field is empty.

Comment: I believe you ment allowed_type_ids[0][2] (2 instead of 6 in the last brackets)?
- And maybe it should be "allowed_type_ids and allowed_type_ids[0][2]" to make sure the list is valid.
Anyway, neat little trick. ;-)

Comment: Do you know if this has recently changed? I swear this had been working for me up until the last couple of days. Now all of a sudden when I view the output from the server in my view, my custom many2many field does not show `x_my_field: [[6, 0, [id1,id2]]` like it used to. It now either shows simply an array of ids, or sometimes it shows an array of other many2many commands, like [[5], [1, id1, {}], [1, id2, {}]]`. Has something changed? I'm using Odoo 10 Saas.

Comment: @flyingL123 Yes something changed. And it not possible to use it this way with last version of Odoo. What you might want is to have a look at this module: web_domain_field https://github.com/OCA/web/pull/567
It allows you to create a field to compute the domain and reuse this field as the domain for your filtering.

Comment: I updated my answer as this solution won't work anymore