# How to check if field 'contains' the value in Odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I'm trying to provide an access for users, who're viewers of the given category.

```xml
    <record id="rule_cost_centre_viewer" model="ir.rule">
        <field name="name">Access for the records for a cost_centre's viewer</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="model_example_module"/>
        <field name="domain_force">[('user_id', 'in', category.viewers.ids)]</field>
        <field name="groups" eval="[(4,ref('group_example_module_user'))]"/>
    </record>
```

The attempt was not successful, I got:

```py
ValueError: <type 'exceptions.NameError'>: "name 'category' is not defined" while u"[('user_id', 'in', category.viewers.ids)]"
```

For the sake of clarity:

```py
class Example(models.Model):
    _name = 'example.module'
    category = fields.Many2one('example.category', 'Category')

class Category(models.Model):
    _name = 'example.category'
    name = fields.Char('Category')
    viewers = fields.Many2many('res.users', 'example_category_rel', 'user_id', 'viewer_id', 'Viewers')
```

What's the problem in here?

Maybe there's a possibility to check.

```xml
<field name="domain_force">[('category.viewers.ids', 'contains', user.id)]</field>
```

since the other way is not working?..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```xml
<field name="domain_force">[('category.viewers', '=', user.id)]</field>
```

Maybe this solution is a bit awkward, but it's working. A similar question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32135853/3146213).

And try to stay in Odoo's guideline for naming fields: `category_id`, `viewer_ids` and so on.

Comment: That is akward, for sure. Thanks for the help!

Comment: About naming fields, aren't those category_id, viewer_ids was appropriate for openerp <= 7.0 versions?