# Is it possible to emulate a "contains" operator for domains? (the inverse of "in")

Tags: python, xml, odoo-10, odoo

I've faced several times the situation in which I need to write a `Many2many`/`One2Many` field in the left part of a domain and a simple record in the right part. Like the `in` operator, but the other way around.

What I did is avoid this situation with workarounds, but now, I come up with nothing. My current situation is the following:

If you install `project` module, you'll see that each `project.task` object can have a unique responsible (`user_id`, is a `Many2one`). If you open tasks view, a filter is automatically loaded to see only your tasks:

```
<filter string="My Tasks" name="my_tasks" domain="[('user_id','=',uid)]"/>
```

But, what I need is to allow the assignment of several users to the same task. So first, I've create a `Many2many` field in `project.task`:

```
user_ids = fields.Many2many(
    comodel_name='res.users',
    string='Project Managers',
    default=lambda self: self.env.user.mapped('id')
)
```

Everything works fine, however, now I need to make the filter work the same way as earlier, but with this field. Here is where I'm stucked and need an hypothetical operator `contains`.

```
<filter string="My Tasks" name="my_tasks" domain="[('user_ids','contains',uid)]"/>
```

Did anyone deal with this situation? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've realized that the operator '=' works as though it was a 'contains' as well. So it's really easy to implement this issue, since the new filter must be exactly like it was but changing the field name:

```
<filter string="My Tasks" name="my_tasks" domain="[('user_ids','=',uid)]"/>
```

I've tried this on version 10 and it's working!

These questions give me the hint:

[Odoo 8: Many2many domain filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32135065/odoo-8-many2many-domain-filter/32135853#32135853)

[How to check if field 'contains' the value in Odoo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45143568/how-to-check-if-field-contains-the-value-in-odoo)

Comment: i think the in operator work aswell even in that situation

Comment: @dccdany you're right, I've just checked and it works with `in` operator too.